# Replacement dialer for AOSP/CM/OctOS

Tags: android

I'd like to find a replacement app for the AOSP dialer by Google.  I've done some preliminary research and am flabbergasted by the state of this kind of app.  I didn't know that contacts and dialer were the same, nor would I have ever presumed that to replace one, I have to replace them both.  I wasn't looking for a new contacts app yet, but am not opposed to replacing it.  I am primarily dissatisfied with the stock app, and I don't make too many calls, so I don't have a long list of features I am looking for.  I find it gets in the way more often than I could even fathom was possible.  You know, given that this is (was?) the primary app of the device while it was being designed.

**What has me aghast**

- The top dialers keep a copy of your contacts (Truecaller and Drupe)
- At least Drupe requires a login to Facebook
- They seem to require a constant data connection
- The companies are keeping a copy (*the* copy?) of your contacts on their servers.
- Presumably, they are profiting from keeping a copy of your current contacts by selling them to someone.  That business model seems to be all the rage nowadays.

**What I dislike about the stock dialer**

- DMTF tones are absurdly loud when dialing a number
- DTMF tones cause some kind of delay or slowdown; trying to press them rapidly induces slow feedback, the far end may not hear them all correctly
- Dialer has no configurability (ie for absurdly loud DTMF tones)
- Backing up and restoring contacts invariably loses some of them for some unknown reason (but it's been mentioned here, so I'm thinking it's a bug of some kind)

**What I am looking for in a dialer (requirements)**

- Compatibility with Android N and its permission system
- Works on AOSP/CM/OctOS
- UI is always highly responsive
- Low CPU/RAM footprint (aka lightweight)
- Made by a reputable firm/developer
- Full featured (supporting all the phone functions my hardware and cell plan do)
- Doesn't get in the way when I am making or receiving phone calls
- No ads
- No sleazy business model
- Don't steal, copy, or rent out my personal information

**Icing on the cake**

- Free software
- Open Source
- Completely separate app from contacts app
- Integrates with Tasker
- Integration with a PC for VoIP calling or other cool whiz-bang features

Comment: That one will be hard to find. While waiting for recommendations, be welcome to my [Dialer](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_dialer#group_76) app list. Unfortunately, most of the privacy-friendly candidates have long not been updated, [Ray Dialer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.t2k269.dialer) being an exception. Not having tried any of them, I cannot give a clear recommendation myself, sorry.